# DOM value property not supported in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup

So, I have a small bit of javascript code that makes a popup div. It works exactly how I expected it to. But then I tried it on IE, and it doesn't work (surprise!). I discovered (shockingly) that IE has a developer console, with javascript breakpoints possible. So, I went through my code, and found out that IE encounters an error on line 4 in the code below:

```
function makePopUp() {
    div = document.getElementById("shell");
    if(!div) {
        email = document.getElementById("email").value;  //HERE IS THE ERROR!
        popupshell = document.createElement("div");
        popupinner = document.createElement("div");
        popupshell.id = "shell";
        popupinner.id = "inner";
        popupinner.innerHTML = "A crazy long string (HTML of the popup)"
        popupshell.appendChild(popupinner);
        document.body.appendChild(popupshell);
    }
    else {  //This just blinks the popup window if it already exists.
        blink(div);
        t = setTimeout("blink(div);",100);
        t = setTimeout("blink(div);",200);
        t = setTimeout("blink(div);",300);
        t = setTimeout("blink(div);",400);
        t = setTimeout("blink(div);",500);
    }
}
```

IE gives me the error "Object doesn't support this property or method". I assume it's referring to the value property of the input tag I have with the the id "email". This property is DOM 1&2... so IE should be able to interpret it. Does anyone have a workaround to this problem, or is my code actually deserving of an error and I'm just stupid?

Comment: Sidenote: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, pass functions.  `setTimeout(function(){blink(div);}, 100);`

Comment: What is `email`?  A div, an input field, a textarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're problem isn't with the "value" attribute. The problem is that you're not declaring your local variables with `var`.

```
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;  //HERE IS THE ERROR!
```

Internet Explorer treats "id" values of elements as properties of `window` that refer to the corresponding DOM node. Without `var`, the variable "email" would be that global symbol and IE doesn't like the idea of you assigning a string to it.

Comment: I don't think that would throw a `Object doesn't support this property or method`, would it?  Though, it is a good idea to use `var` (unless `email` really was a global variable).

Comment: Well I don't know what IE would throw; it does some weird stuff.

Comment: ... in fact I get exactly that error in IE8. IE9 is quite a different animal from IE8 :-)

Comment: @Rocket SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method 
show, line 20 character 1